# Clifford algebra formulation of the Nambu-goto action

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, string-theory, action, clifford-algebra

Using the wedge product one can pair the generators the Clifford algebra $Cl_{1,3}(\mathbb{R})$ to produce 2-vectors (area elements).

The Nambu-Goto action is a statement on the evolution of invariant area elements of the space-time metric.

Is it appropriate to use these 2-vectors to formulate the Nambu-Goto action.

---

The possible 2-vectors of $Cl_{1,3}(\mathbb{R})$ are:

$$
\gamma_0\gamma_1,\; \gamma_0\gamma_2,\; \gamma_0\gamma_3,\; \gamma_1\gamma_2,\; \gamma_1\gamma_3,\; \gamma_2\gamma_3
$$

The first three bi-vectors are wedge products involving time $t$ wedge a position $x,y$ or $z$. Intuitively they appear relevant to the Nambu-Goto action.

Can we obtain the Nambu-Goto action using the Lagrangian of an invariant sum of area elements:

$$
S=\int \mathrm dt\, \mathrm  dx\, \mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz \sqrt{\left( A(t,x) \gamma_0 \wedge \gamma_1 \right)^2 + \left( B(t,y) \gamma_0 \wedge \gamma_2 \right)^2 + \left( C(t,z) \gamma_0 \wedge \gamma_3 \right)^2}
$$

Or, perhaps one should use another combination of 2-vectors?

Comment: What is the square root of a Clifford matrix, what is the motivation for randomly sticking in Clifford elements into a square root of a well-defined quantity, what would happen if you did this in a QFT context for a point particle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP considers a field theory in 3+1D, while the Nambu-Goto string action is a field theory in 1+1D. OP probably has a [$p$-brane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brane) action
$$ S_p~=~-T_0\int d^{p+1}\sigma ~\sqrt{-\det\left(\partial_{\alpha} X\cdot \partial_{\beta} X\right)_{\alpha\beta}} $$
in mind. FWIW, as long as spinor variables doesn't enter the theory, it seems likely that Clifford calculus and gamma matrices are not needed.